# Current rating of relay with daisy chained parallel power supply

Tags: ac, relay

I am using relays to turn on and off appliances that may work on mains or DC voltage. My question is in regards to mains voltage. I am hooking up the live wire to the com pin and the live of the appliance to the normally closed pin, so when the relay is turned on, the circuit is complete.

Lets say for example the power rating of the contacts of the relay is 125VAC 10A. As per my understanding, 10A is the amount of current that flow between the 2 contacts. What I am doing is I am daisy chaining the com pins of the relays to create a parallel circuit, so the current across these may be higher than 10A, depending on how many appliances are turned on, although still, the current between the individual contacts of relays will be lower. Can I still use a relay with this rating?

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic. Click on edit and then the schematic symbol.

Comment: The Normally Closed contact of a relay is connected to the COM terminal when the relay is NOT powered.  The Normally Open  contact will be connected to COM when the relay is energised.  Your description will have the appliance powered when there is no power applied to the relay coil.

Answer (score 0):

> So can I still use a relay with this rating?

Yes, you can, since each relay switches on only one appliance.

[image]